# Perform .click() on each children of ul class using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to click on each children returned by ul class starting from the last index.

Code I have tried but is not working is :

```
//Returns 5 children
cy.get('ul').children().each(($el,indexFromEnd) => {
    $el.eq(indexFromEnd).click()
})
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: @AlapanDas No error as the Test bypasses loop

Comment: Did you find a solution? I had to cy.wrap($el)...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using this. Not an elegant solution but it should work. Here we checking the length of `ul` elements and then using an for loop starting from the end to the beginning clicking elements.

```
cy.get('ul').children().its('length').then((itemLen) => {
    for (var i = itemLen - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cy.get('ul' + ':nth-child' + '(' + i + ')').click()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see [docs for `.each()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Arguments)

> **Arguments**
> callbackFn (Function)
>
> Pass a function that is invoked with the following arguments:
>
> value
> index
> collection

The value argument is the single collection element at position `index` (from start), so there is no need to use `$eq()`

```js
cy.get('ul').children().each(($el,index) => {
  $el.click()
})
```

Or reverse order

```js
cy.get('ul').children().each(($el,index,collection) => {
  const indexFromEnd = collection.length - index -1;
  collection.eq(indexFromEnd).click()
})
```

Tested with

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="console.log(1)"></li>
  <li onclick="console.log(2)"></li>
  <li onclick="console.log(3)"></li>
</ul>
```

Prints `3, 2, 1`

Comment: This works, already tried but my purpose is to start clicking items from the end of index, so it should start with -1 and end at 0.

Comment: Yeah I was a bit slow understanding that

Comment: If the `.click()` has some slow side effect the results may not be sequential. Is that a problem?

Comment: That is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get `array` from `children()` with `.toArray()` and then apply `reverse()`, use `forEach` instead of `each` & use `$($el)` instead of `$el`. No need to use `eq`, just perform `click()`. Complete code is as below.

```
//Returns 5 children
cy.get('ul').children().toArray().reverse().forEach($el) => {
    $($el).click();
});
```